# Error transforming from frame 'base_link' to frame 'odom'

Tags: odometry, tf2, tf-broadcaster

I'm trying to write my odometry for a robot. I started by publishing tf odom and I got an error. It is worth noting that when I run rviz with joint_state_publisher without gazebo, I can make odom a fixed frame, but when I try to run with gazebo, with gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher and switch the fixed frame to odom, the wheels disappear in rviz and the console shows the following message: "Error transforming from frame 'base_link' to frame 'odom'".
Tf_tree:
[image]
With Gazebo:
[image]

Without Gazebo:
[image]

Rviz output:
[image]

My state_publisher code:

```py
from math import sin, cos, pi
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster, TransformStamped

class StatePublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        rclpy.init()
        super().__init__('state_publisher')

        qos_profile = QoSProfile(depth=10)
        self.odomPub = self.create_publisher(Odometry, 'odom', qos_profile)
        self.broadcaster = TransformBroadcaster(self)
        self.nodeName = self.get_name()
        self.get_logger().info("{0} started".format(self.nodeName))

        degree = pi / 180.0
        loop_rate = self.create_rate(30)

        # robot state
        tilt = 0.
        tinc = degree
        swivel = 0.
        angle = 0.
        height = 0.
        hinc = 0.005
        try:
            while rclpy.ok():
                rclpy.spin_once(self)
                self.update()
                loop_rate.sleep()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def update(self):

        # message declarations
        odom_trans = TransformStamped()
        odom_trans.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        odom_trans.child_frame_id = 'base_link'


        now = self.get_clock().now()
        # update transform

        odom_trans.header.stamp = now.to_msg()
        odom_trans.transform.translation.x = 0.
        odom_trans.transform.translation.y = 0.0
        odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0
        odom_trans.transform.rotation = euler_to_quaternion(0, 0, 0) # roll,pitch,ya
        # send the joint state and transfor
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans)
        
        odom = Odometry()
        odom.header.stamp = now.to_msg()
        odom.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = euler_to_quaternion(0, 0, 0)
        odom.child_frame_id = 'base_link'
        odom.twist.twist.linear.x = 0.0
        odom.twist.twist.linear.y = 0.0
        odom.twist.twist.angular.z = 0.0
        # This will adjust as needed per iteration
        self.odomPub.publish(odom)
        #self.get_logger().info("UPDATE_END")

    def spin(self):
        loop_rate = self.create_rate(30)
        self.get_logger().info("SPIN")
        while rclpy.ok():
            
            self.get_logger().info("IN")
            self.update()

            loop_rate.sleep()
            self.get_logger().info("AFTER_SLEEP")
        


def euler_to_quaternion(roll, pitch, yaw):
    qx = sin(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) - cos(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    qy = cos(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) + sin(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    qz = cos(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2) - sin(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2)
    qw = cos(roll/2) * cos(pitch/2) * cos(yaw/2) + sin(roll/2) * sin(pitch/2) * sin(yaw/2)
    return Quaternion(x=qx, y=qy, z=qz, w=qw)

def main():
    node = StatePublisher()
    # loop_rate = node.create_rate(30)
    # try:
    #     while rclpy.ok():
    #         rclpy.spin_once(node)
    #         node.update()
    #         loop_rate.sleep()
    # except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #     node.get_logger().info("LOX")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```